# How to make a good mash potato

Tags: potatoes, mash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a silky smooth, rich mash?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4495/how-can-i-make-a-silky-smooth-rich-mash)

My mash potatoes are usually not very tasty.

I sometimes add some cheese or butter (together with milk) but I never manage to make a good one! Probably the quantities are wrong.

Could you give me some help ?
Thanks

Comment: If rfusca's proposed duplicate isn't enough for you, you might want to clarify what's wrong with your potatoes. Too dry? Too watery? Too bland?

Comment: I hope you don't purée them?!?

Comment: It is best if you describe your process in more detail. 
Do you mash them warm or cold?
Do you mash them with a fork or a food processor?
How much milk and butter do you add?
What kind of potatoes? (baking potato or not)

Comment: This seems somewhere between a duplicate and a [recipe request](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-food-related-questions). By all means please clarify what's wrong with your mash and we'll be happy to reopen this question - as long as the problem is more specific than "bad taste" or "wrong texture".

Answer (score 1):

I usually season my mashed potatoes with salt, pepper and *lots* of muscat nut.

Apart from that, boil the potatoes in really salty water. The difference between adding the salt to the water rather than adding it later on is really astounding.

Answer (score 0):

Using a potato ricer will make the mash smoother.

Use more butter, and use heavy/double cream instead of milk, add salt and pepper.